# I want to pull latest post and embed other 2 first result posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

User will search/submit at the same time.

```
<input id="user-submitted-title" name="user-submitted-title" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Search', 'usp'); ?>"<?php if (usp_check_required('usp_title')) echo $usp_required; ?> class="usp-input">
```

This one is the form from wordpress plugin, and its only for a title, and I use that only. When user submits this by title, I have other code which will add post into my wordpress site by bunch of other codes.

I already have a query:

```
<?php
include 'wp-load.php';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()):
    $data = '';
    while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
    $data .= '<h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 0; margin: 0px 0 10px 0px;">'.get_the_title().'</h1>';
    $data .= '<div class="description">'.do_shortcode(get_the_content()).'</div>';

endwhile;endif;
echo $data;  ?>
```

So this one basically shows their or the latest post from the wordpress site on same page with search/submit button.

Except this I want to acomplish that to get and embed content of the other site posts found by query from input and embed them after the one above.

I tried something with new query like:

```
    <?php
include 'wp-load.php';

    $querys = new WP_Query('post_title='.get_the_title().'');

    if($querys->have_posts()) : while($querys->have_posts()) : $querys->the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    the_excerpt(); // or the_content(); for full post content
    endwhile;endif;
?>
```

But this `$querys = new WP_Query('post_title='.get_the_title().'');` does not seem to work.
How to do this?
Plus this second query does not work for links, outside loop, how to solve that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried 
`$querys = new WP_Query('post_title="'.get_the_title().'"');` this one.
or may be this one

```
$querys = new WP_Query('s' => get_the_title()); // custom search query
```